# 'CLLocation' is not convertible to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to make use of multiple tutorials to teach myself Swift.

So far I have this code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup our Location Manager
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        textView.delegate = self

        //Setup our Map View
        myMapView.delegate = self
        myMapView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
        myMapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        //theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)

        let spanX = 0.007
        let spanY = 0.007
        var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myMapView.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        myMapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

        if (myLocations.count > 1){
            var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
            var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

            let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
            let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
            var a = [c1, c2]
            var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
            myMapView.addOverlay(polyline)
        }

    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: manager.location, title: textView.text, subtitle: "SubTitle");
        myMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

This line

```
var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: manager.location, title: textView.text, subtitle: "SubTitle");
```

is causing this error:

> 'CLLocation' is not convertible to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

My other Swift file is:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title:NSString!
    var subtitle: NSString!

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: NSString!, subtitle: NSString!) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is fairly explicit.  The `init` wants a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and you're trying to give it a `CLLocation` instead.  I suspect you want to pass the `coordinate` property of `manager.location` rather than the location itself.

Comment: Philip, Thanks so much, I'm sure it would of been something easy but i couldn't figure it

Answer (score 2):

CLLocation has a property named "coordinate" of type CLLocationCoordinate2D, so you can access that field and get CLLocationCoordinate2D of your CLLocation